# Is it possible to use the Chrome Devtools Protocol within an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-devtools-protocol

The Chrome Devtools protocol (CDP) is super powerful and has a lot of useful APIs to retrieve low-level metrics from a page.

Is it possible to use it from a chrome extension ?

Right now, I'm using the injected script to retrieve what I want from the page I'm using the extension on. But if I can use the CDP it opens much more info that I can display on the extension.

Comment: Yes, see `chrome.debugger`.

Comment: Oh nice! my bad I missed that. Thanks!